# How to pass values from one handlerFunc to another go-gin

Tags: go

I have rest API defined as

```
    apis.GET(/home, validatationHandler , dashboardHandler)
```

I want pass some data from validatationHandler to dashboardHandler. For this I thought of using header. To set the data I use this in validatationHandler

```
    c.Writer.Header().Set("myheader", "mytoken")
    c.Next()
```

and in dashboardHandler I tried to access it using

```
fmt.Println(c.Request.Header.Get("myheader"))
```

But the value is always nil. Any idea how can I set and retrieve headers? Is there any other way I can pass on the data from 1 handler to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass values via `gin.Context`
Use `ctx.Set(k, v)` in fisrt one and `ctx.Get(k)` in the next.

So How to Use It:

```
ctx.Set("myKey", 100)
```

and get it using

```
v, ok := ctx.Get("myKey")
if ok {
   actualValue := v.(int) // you need to type convert it as it returns interface.
}
```

See [context.go](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/develop/context.go#L159)

Comment: Looks good. But this returns both value and an exists Boolean. How can I access just the value?

Comment: ok yes this works and even this works -  fmt.Println(c.MustGet("myKey"))

Comment: yes, but `MustGet` will through panic and stop your server if the key is not exists in the context. So isn't it obvious you check yourself and have the flexibility to handle your error yourself.